# Properly Configuring the PI ODBC Client so that RODBC can be used

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc, osisoft

I am trying to use Osisoft's PI ODBC client.  I am on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.  Because of some issues with 32 to 64 bit connecions, Osisoft came up with [this](http://techsupport.osisoft.com/techsupport/NonTemplates/KB/article.aspx?id=KB00234) workaround.  After following the directions I was able to see the PI-ODBC driver in the ODBC Data Source Administrator and I was able to configure it.  The problem is that when I open R and use the package RODBC I get an error.  This is the code I used and the error it generated:

```
> library("RODBC", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library")
```

> ch <- odbcConnect("PIWHI")

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=PIWHI") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM014, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
2: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=PIWHI") : ODBC connection failed
```

I'm lost as to why this is not working.  I know everything with setting up the ODBC client worked...a rep from OSIsoft confirmed this.  I'm not sure why R isn't able to connect to it

Comment: So I think I know what is going on. On my 64 bit machine, I'm able to configure the ODBC driver as a 32 bit data source.  However, when I try to configure as a 64 bit data source it gives me the error of architecture mismatch.  My question now is how to I use RODBC to only connect to the 32 bit data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out the PI ODBC driver is a 32 bit driver.  Because I was using a 64 bit version of R, a connection could not take place.  I changed to a 32 bit version of R and it worked well.

Comment: Aha.  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200656876-Changing-and-R-Installation-32-vs-64-bit-version-